# problem in connecting node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, connection, frontend, backend

I am building a website using node.js and mongoDB backend. Whenever I start running the server, frontend works completely fine but I am unable to connect to my database. Running `mongod` command always gives the message

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-10T10:46:27.043+5:30"},"s:"I","c":"Network","id":23016,
"ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connection","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

I simultaneously executed `npm start` from the frontend and backend folders. The `npm start` from the backend folder gives

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./server.js`
Listening on port 8080
MongoDB connected
```

The `npm start` from the frontend folder gives

```
App running at:
- Local: http://localhost:8080/
- Network: http://192.168.56.1:8080/
```

But whenever the open it, it gives

```
Cannot GET /
```

Is it because I couldn’t connect to the database? I’m fairly new to this. I can’t seem to understand the reason behind this. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot GET /
```

means `http://localhost:8080/` has no method defined in your app.
if you are using expressJs
in your server.js
add

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('No More error')
})
```

*Here we are saying: send "No More error" whenever user opens "/" path.*

*`i.e http://localhost:8080/ in your case.`*